# Why doesn't my setTimeout callback not get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm busy building a flash-card game. I want to give the user a visible countdown before a card get's flashed on screen. My script for the countdown looks like this:

```
let downSeconds = 5;
while (downSeconds > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#timerDisplay").text = downSeconds;
        downSeconds--;
    }, 1000);
}

$(".detail-card").removeClass("hidden");
```

If I didn't want the updated seconds I'd just use a 5000ms 'setTimeOut'. I did before try with a `setInterval`, with a delay of 1000ms, so every time it elapses it updates the seconds.

Now, if I put a breakpoint on either line of the `setTimeOut` callback, and only there, nothing happens when the `setTimeout` is invoked, so the seconds display never updates, and I'm in an infinite loop, because `downSeconds--;` is never invoked, so `downSeconds` keeps the value of 5 all throughout.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need setInterval, not setTimeout - timeout is fired once

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous and only tells the browser to execute the passed function as soon as possible, but not before x milliseconds have passed. But your browser is busy running the `while` loop hence he has no time to execute the function.

Comment: it doesn't get called because your tight `while (downSeconds > 0)` never lets it get called ... thousands and millions of timeouts will get "started", that will never fire, and then you'll run out of memory or your browser will tell you that a script is making the system unresponsive - funny you never mentioned that

Comment: @WaldemarIce I know that, that's why I have a `while` loop around it. I'm using `setTimeout` so that I had a simple 1 second timer to decrement the countdown seconds.

Comment: With `while` you just fired 5 timers at at once. They will run for one second, all at same time. You must use setInterval and stop it with clearInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout runs the code later, while the while loop runs "now". You can't successfully combine the two.. So, you have to write your code differently, something like this should work:

```
let downSeconds = 5;
function doCountDown() {
    downSeconds--;
    $("#timerDisplay").text = downSeconds;
    if (downSeconds > 0) {
        setTimeout(doCountDown, 1000);
    } else {
        $(".detail-card").removeClass("hidden");
    }
}
setTimeout(doCountDown, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use ES7 and await the loop for a second:

```
const time = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));

(async function(){
   let downSeconds = 5;
   while (downSeconds > 0) {
    await time(1000);
    $("#timerDisplay").text = downSeconds;
    downSeconds--;
   }
   $(".detail-card").removeClass("hidden");
})()
```

Comment: What's the `promise` for?

Comment: @profk the promise will be resolved after *ms*. So when we do `await time(1000);` it creates a promise which will be awaited so the code continues in a second

Comment: The downvoter is probably stuck with a years old VB.NET, and cannot have an understanding of things async. I see all the answers are downvoted though, and they're all quite valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` call is asynchronous,
and so by the time the 1000 milliseconds scheduled by the first call to `setTimeout` elapses,
the while-loop will have executed its body thousands of times,
each time scheduling a new job with `setTimeout`,
causing massive scheduling work to the JavaScript engine.
The engine is too busy to execute the function,
and it just keeps getting worse,
as the loop keeps running and keeps scheduling more and more.
I would expect your execution environment to become unresponsive and unable to make progress, unable to actually call the first function scheduled.

Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead, for example:

```
let counter = 5;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
    $("#timerDisplay").text = counter;
    counter--;
    if (counter == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $(".detail-card").removeClass("hidden");
    }
}, 1000);
```